# Compose ErrorMessage in Tsql

Tags: database, t-sql, null

I want to add a ErrorMessage Column into my AfterParse_CA_Events. So i can see which data is missing for my table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AfterParse_CA_Events](
[EventID] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[MessageID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[cdtprFunction] [varchar](32) NULL,
[CreationDate] [datetime] NULL,
[MsgDefIdr] [varchar](32) NULL,
[CFI] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MndtryVlntryEvtTp] [varchar](32) NULL,
[EventProcessingType] [varchar](4) NULL,
[EventType] [varchar](4) NULL,
[RecordDate] [date] NULL,
[EffectiveDate] [date] NULL,
[DueBillRdmDate] [date] NULL,
[OldQuantity] [varchar](32) NULL,
[PaymentDate] [date] NULL,
[LastChangeBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LastChangeDate] [datetime] NULL,
[EventDescription] [varchar](max) NULL,
[CUSIP] [varchar](32) NULL,
[MQ_DateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[Symbol2] [varchar](32) NULL,
[AssetClass] [varchar](5) NULL,
[AssetType] [varchar](5) NULL,
[DividendType] [varchar](5) NULL,
[ExDividendDate] [date] NULL,
[LSCI_DateOfRecord] [date] NULL,
[RoundingDesc] [varchar](4) NULL,
[CompleteStatus] [varchar](4) NULL,
[ErrorMessage] [varchar](100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AfterParse_CA_Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EventID] ASC,
    [MessageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is all the columns I have. I want to check LSCI_DateOfRecord, CFI, RecordDate, EffectiveDate, DueBillRdmDate, PaymentDate, CUSIP, Symbol2 and ExDividendDate. If either the columns missing the data(null), i want to show the column name in the ErrorMessage column.

I have written a simple query for LSCI_DateOfRecord, but I do not know how to compose the Error Message  when there are multiple columns missing data.

if both the LSCI_DateOfRecord and DueBillRdmDate is null, I want the ErrorMessage to look like 'LSCI_DateOfRecord DueBillRdmDate missing '.

my code :

```
--build the ErrorMessage for  AfterParse_CA_Events
declare @errorMessge varchar(1000)

select case 
            when ace.LSCI_DateOfRecord IS NULL then ' LSCI_RecordDate'
            --when ace.DueBillRdmDate IS null then ' DueBillRdmDate' 
             else 'good'
             end as ErrorMessage
             ,*
from AfterParse_CA_Events ace
```

Could any one help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing it correctly, you just need to concat them. The column wouldn't be persisted in your DB unless you did a check on insert. That is, for the triggers or what ever you are using to insert your data, you'd have to check the values being inserted, or do a follow on update.

```
select
    *,
    ErrorColumn =  
       case when ace.LSCI_DateOfRecord IS NULL then 'LSCI_RecordDate' else '' end
       +
       case when ace.DueBillRdmDate  IS NULL then 'DueBillRdmDate ' else '' end
       +
       ...
from AfterParse_CA_Events ace
```

Or on an update...

```
update t
set t.ErrorColumn  = <case statement from above>
from AfterParse_CA_Events t
```

An important note here is the `else ''`. I did this because by default the else would be `NULL` and `NULL + <anything> = NULL`. For example:

```
select null + 'someString'
```

Comment: No worries at all @Rachel